# Does Orbitdb have extra dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ipfs, orbitdb

For Orbitdb to work with IPFS, perhaps there are some extra dependencies which are not mentioned anywhere specifically. I tried creating a simple key-value db referring from the docs:

`orbit.js`

```
const IPFS = require("ipfs");
const OrbitDB = require("orbit-db");

    const ipfsOptions = {
      EXPERIMENTAL: {
        pubsub: true
      }
    };

    const ipfs = await IPFS.create(ipfsOptions);
    const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(ipfs);
    const db = await orbitdb.create("test", "keyvalue", {
      overwrite: true,
      replicate: true,
      accessController: {
        type: "ipfs",
        admin: ["*"],
        write: ["*"]
      }
    });
    await db.set("hello", "world");
    console.log(db.all);
```

I had the following dependencies in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ipfs": "^0.46.0",
    "orbit-db": "^0.24.1"
}
```

It threw the following error:

`Trace: Error: Could not append entry, key "..." is not allowed to write to the log`

I tried resolving it but nothing seemed to work. Now, comes the interesting part. So, I am currently developing the frontend part of the code that will use Orbitdb. Out of sheer luck (curiosity), I copy pasted the file `orbit.js` to the root folder containing the frontend code. Running the same file there, worked perfectly, creating the db successfully! Here are all the dependencies and dev-dependencies in the `package.json` for the frontend code (which is in Angular):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.4",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "3.0.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "5.0.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "5.0.0",
    "@nebular/security": "5.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "5.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^13.0.2",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "ckeditor": "4.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "env-paths": "^2.2.0",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "ipfs": "^0.46.0",
    "it-all": "^1.0.2",
    "leaflet": "1.2.0",
    "metamask-logo": "^2.2.1",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "orbit-db": "^0.24.1",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "test-ipfs-example": "^2.0.3",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "web3": "^1.2.9",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.4",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  }
```

I know most of these dependencies don't even relate to Orbitdb, I can definitely narrow them down to particular dependencies but can someone throw some light onto why it worked here. I'm totally new to using Orbitdb.

Answer (score 0):

OrbitDB already handle its dependencies correctly

Your code should work and you can even simplify it

```js
const start = async () => {
  const ipfs = await IPFS.create();
  const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(ipfs);
  const db = await orbitdb.create("test", "keyvalue", {
    overwrite: true,
    replicate: true,
    accessController: {
      write: ["*"],
    },
  });
  await db.set("hello", "world");
  console.log(db.all);
  db.close();
  ipfs.stop();
};

start();
```